# JQuery selector fail

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain me please, how does this button

```
<button id="opener" class="ignoreRedirectionAlert">@Resources.Localization.add_record</button>
```

Can trigger this function:

```
$(":submit, :radio, .link_button, #ShowAll,#ShowActive").on("click", function () {
    submitClicked = true;
});
```

Also, i have tried adding `button:not('.ignoreRedirectionAlert')` in the selector - same result, for no reason this button triggers this function.

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default behaviour of `BUTTON` is `submit`, thus event is attached using `:submit` selector.

To exclude use

```
:submit:not(.ignoreRedirectionAlert)
```

OR

```
<button type="button" id="opener" class="ignoreRedirectionAlert">@Resources.Localization.add_record</button>
```

Comment: @rainbowShiningUnicorn see https://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/ "Note that some browsers treat `<button>` element as `type="submit"` implicitly"

Answer (score 0):

It matches the `:submit` selector, as by default a `<button>` element is `type="submit"`, unless otherwise specified.

To have the selector avoid this element use `:submit:not(.ignoreRedirectionAlert)` or add `type="button"` to the element in your HTML. Exactly which you need would depend on whether you expect the button to submit its parent `form` element.